# Windows cmd copy not working as I expect

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, ms-dos

I am used to using linux command line so a little unfamilar with windows dos. I am trying to add a copy file line into my script but it is not working. So I tried the same thing on the cmd promt and still its not working. So I did some tests, I found a way to make it work by going to the source folder and do `copy * dest`. However I want to do `copy source\* dest` but this seems to not work. Here is the output of my testing:

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\audioTest\resources>copy * C:\Users\test\Desktop\build-TGW2AudioTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\targetDbg /y
data_input.txt
open-audio-doc.png
open-data-doc.png
PESQ.exe
ref_alastair.wav
ref_female.wav
ref_male.wav
        7 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\test\Desktop\audioTest\resources>copy C:\Users\test\Desktop\audioTest\resource\* C:\Users\test\Desktop\build-TGW2AudioTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\targetDbg /y
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Why does the first one work, but the second one does not?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in a `cmd` shell on Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah its weird, I thought maybe a permissions thing but both locations are in a folder on my desktop. But it says it can't find specified path.... I am actually calling it from this path so that is even more strange.

Comment: not sure if this is a typo or not, but your folder is shown as being called 'resources' and the copy command is referring to a directory called resource, without the 's' in resources.

Comment: @Richie086 ...oh!

Comment: Feeling a bit silly now... hey ho.... if you want to put it in an answer i'll fix you up with some points!... thanks : )

Comment: Will do.  Glad I could help

Comment: try wrapping your source and destination in quotes i.e. copy "<src>" "<dest>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
copy C:\Users\test\Desktop\audioTest\resources\* C:\Users\test\Desktop\build-TGW2AudioTest-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\targetDbg /y
```

The full path to your directory was

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\audioTest\resources\
```

however your example left the "s" off of the name of the resources folder